# Columns disappear on page refresh

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

Using SharePoint Designer 2010, if I add a table column to a XsltListViewWebPart it shows in the designer (always) but only shows in the browser once -- if the browser is refreshed the, a different view is displayed from then on.

For example, I start with a simple list and insert it on page (e.g., DataView), preview in designer, save, and preview in browser. All fine.  Choose a column in table, insert column to left, preview in designer, save, and preview in browser. All fine. (just empty column). Refresh browser, all columns except title disappear (and Attachment columns appears!).  No way to recover except delete and start over. Seems to depend on where in the site / subsite page exists whether this occurs or not (e.g., default.aspx has this error, but not page in sub-site used for trying things out.)

More info: It seems that if any change to the XLST is made,

```
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/>
    <FieldRef Name="FY"/>
    <FieldRef Name="Due_x0020_Date"/>
    <FieldRef Name="Status"/>
    <FieldRef Name="Clock"/>
    <FieldRef Name="Program"/>
    <FieldRef Name="Note_x0020_to_x0020_PM"/>
</ViewFields>
```

is changed to this (on the server):

```
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name="Attachments"/>
        <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/>
    </ViewFields>
```

and can't be changed at that point.  (I guess.)

There isn't an `<!-- IE 9 -->` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Check for commented section in the page something like `<!--IE 9 -->`. Delete this part and retry